# Header with transparent navbar

Tags: image, header, navbar

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2hfz.jpg)

is it possible to create something like the picture?
(so a header with an image and at the bottom side of it a semitransparent navbar ( so I can see the bottom of the picture)

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please click the checkmark to the left of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was that I used `background-image` to add the image to the background of your header, a whitespace div to move the navbar to the bottom, and then added an RGBA color  (red, green, blue, alpha, with alpha meaning transparency) onto the `background-color` of the navbar. Here is my code:

[Codesandbox Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/answer-to-the-question-header-with-transparent-navbar-pxjel)

Or

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
    border: 5px solid black;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/7/Top_view.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format");
    /* background-size: cover; */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

div#whitespace {
    height: calc(100% - 40px); /* 20 px is the height of the navbar */
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);
    height: 40px;
}

a {
    /* text-decoration: none; */
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="whitespace"></div>
  <nav>
    <a href=".">Home</a>
    <a href=".">Link 1</a>
    <a href=".">Link 2</a>
    <a href=".">Link 3</a>
  </nav>
</header>
```

What I am doing here is defining a header element with the `background-image` of `url("https://images.unsplash.com/7/Top_view.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format")`. Now `url()` is a CSS function that allows you to include a file, namely our header image. Then, we set `background-size` to `100% 100%`, so the image will resize to fit the dimensions of our header and completely fill the header. We also set `background-repeat` to `no-repeat` so the image will not repeat (though it is unnecessary because the image already fills all of the header elements). Then, I add styles to the whitespace div, making the height of the div 100% (or all the height of our header) and subtracting the height of the div (40px), and I use the CSS function calc which allows me to do mathematical operations on some CSS units. So, by using this whitespace div, it pushes the navbar down to the bottom so it is placed correctly. Finally, for our navbar, I use flexbox to align the items and evenly space the links. Then, I set the background color to `rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35)`. This is `rgb(255, 255, 255` which is white, but now we set the transparency (alpha) value to 0.35, making the color transparent so we can see the background image under the navbar.

Comment: Thank you man, but is it possible to make it responsive?

Comment: @Sas what do you mean by responsive? When resizing, it is pretty ok, other than the image getting resized (:( I can't have otherwise I don't think without having white spots some places)

Comment: @Sas please respond so I can improve my answer :)